# Reference textbooks for calculating pressures/stress/strain/tensors?

Tags: reference-request, physical-properties-of-materials, forcefields, stress-strain

Is there a good reference textbook for calculating pressures/stress/strain/tensors in materials - vapor, liquids and solids? Pure physics is fine, but it would be a bonus if it also included force-field derivations, particularly electrostatics like Ewalds and the other flavors.

I am hoping to find a good reference that kind of "derives it all" in a straightforward manner that I can use as an introductory textbook for teaching these concepts at  an undergraduate level.

I am not after code that can do these calculations. I do not feel that citing the GROMACS manual is an acceptable source for these concepts for undergraduates. However, they should be able to write their own code for simple systems with the help of the reference.

Comment: Following......

Comment: I wonder if you or @RoshanShrestha found anything over the last 8+ months? A self-answer or any answer will be qualified for the silver necromancer badge since the question remained unanswered for 6+ months!